# Tengo un error de ruta y no puedo solucionarlo

Tags: reactjs

El tema es el siguiente, tengo este proyecto ecomerce, en el que estoy tratando de usar el useContext, todo iba bien hasta hasta que en uno de los componente sucedio un error.

El error esta puntualizado en dos componentes:

Tengo el componente llamado: "almacenElement.jsx" que contiene lo siguiente:

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { dataContext } from "../Components/DataContext"

export const AlmacenarElement = () => {
  const { almacenar} =useContext(dataContext)
  
  return almacenar.map(( product )=>{
    return (<>
    <div className="conteiner" key={product.id}>
      <div>Producto:{product.title}</div>
      <div>Precio:{product.precio}</div>
    </div> 
    </>)
  })
}
```

Lo que hace este componente es pedir informacion usando el useContext, extrayendo asi de la API los objetos y renderizarlos en un carrito, el componente useContext es este:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const dataContext = createContext() 

export const DataProvider = ({children}) =>{
  const [ store, setStore] = useState([])//este es para renderizar Cart
  const [ almacenar, setAlmacenar] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setStore(json))},[])
  

  return(<>
    <dataContext.Provider value={{store, almacenar, setAlmacenar}}>
      {children}
    </dataContext.Provider>
  </>)
}
```

El problema surge al tratar de exportar el componente "AlmacenarElement.jsx" a un componente llamado "Almacenar.jsx" el se renderizara en "App.jsx", pero al exportar el componente "AlmacenarElement.jsx" hacia "Almacenar.jsx" da este error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Pages/Almacen/AlmacenarElement.jsx 6:0-56
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../Components/DataContext' in 'D:\react\Proyectos-React\ecommerce\src\Pages\Almacen'     

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

llevo como 3 horas tratando de ver como solucionarlo, pero no hubo caso, no puedo solucionarlo.

Dejo imagenes para mayor ilustracion:

[Imagenes ilustrativas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neGhC.png)

[image: AlmacenElement.jsx]

[image: dataBase/useContext]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
repositorio github por si quieren verlo mas completo: https://github.com/San-dei/ecomerce-nuevo.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en:

`import { dataContext } from "../Components/DataContext"`

Al llamar `"../"` estas obteniendo la carpeta `almacen` y los componentes dentro de `pages`.

Cambia esa linea de código a:

`import { dataContext } from "../../Components/DataContext"`

Comment: Funciono!, te amo jajaj